# Alternative method of SQL WHERE in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Dear coders and stackoverflow users;

Yesterday I've fixed my SQL Queries with JOINS with the help of stackoverflow users - the post could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535578/mysql-queries-using-join-union-etc-solved)

While the SQL Query works wonders, I haven't been able to find a replacement to the queries below;

```
SELECT pID, pname, pstartdate, penddate, photel, pcity FROM projects WHERE pstatus = 'active'
SELECT pID, pname, pstartdate, penddate, photel, pcity FROM projects WHERE pstatus = 'inactive'
```

Perhaps a PHP alternative could work better than another SQL Query, although I am not entirely sure. Trying WHILE() and IF() statements gives an endless loop thus so far my issue has not been solved.
I tried the followings;

```
while( $pstatus == "active" ) {
// do this.
}
```

and

```
if( $pstatus == "active" ) {
//do this.
}elseif( $pstatus == "inactive" ) {
//do that.
};
```

---

I have two tables where in the first one it shows the 'active' projects while on the other one it shows the 'inactive' projects. I did this easily with the SQL Queries above although since I implemented a new SQL where I also select projects, I was wondering if there is a method of replacing the said two queries with a PHP equivalent.

Perhaps in order to clarify this I'll add my code;

```
if ($pactive = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT pID, pname, pstartdate, penddate, photel, pcity FROM projects WHERE pstatus = 'active'")) {
$pactive->execute();
$pactive->store_result();

$pactive->bind_result($apID, $apName, $apSDate, $apEDate, $apHotel, $apCity);
$pacount = $pactive->num_rows; }
```

As you can see having two queries for this is quite inefficient.

Does anyone know how to do this in PHP or perhaps with a single line of SQL Query that I could implement on my code?

Comment: Uh.....what? This is not very clear. What have you tried and what have been the issues?

Comment: But whats the actual issue over here post it.

Comment: I have updated the post. Please revise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick example of what I ***think*** you're trying to achieve would be as follows:

```
$pactive = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT pID, pname, pstartdate, penddate, photel, pcity FROM projects WHERE (pstatus = 'active' OR pstatus = 'inactive')");
$pactive->execute();
```

PHP:

```
while($row = $pactive->fetch())
    {
    if($row['pstatus'] == 'active')
        {
        //do this
        }
    elseif($row['pstatus'] == 'inactive')
        {
        //do this
        }
    }
```

You may want to consider using a `switch` for such a short if/else statement: [PHP Switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: yes! It is exactly what I've been trying to achieve. Perhaps my description was a bit vague - I apologize for this. Although testing this out, it doesn't return values. I'm revising my my code right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT pID, pname, pstartdate, penddate, photel, pcity FROM projects WHERE pstatus in ('active','inactive')
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and avoid getting down votes!

Comment: How do I implement this with bind_results?

Comment: Single line of SQL code instead of you two SQL statements.

Comment: so it goes as bind_results($variables..) and then while() loop?