# rowspan in PHP while loop with a lot of data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table

I am currently working on my tables and I group my results according to customer's room IDs. I do that via my sql query.

> [The query can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535578/mysql-queries-using-join-union-etc-solved)

The tricky part is arranging the output with `rowspan` automatically added. Currently the table I have displays my results as;

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| rID    UID    Name    Surname   Room Type   Total    Paid  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1035   1010   John    Doe        double      200      200  |
| 1035   1011   Jane    Doe        double      200      200  |
| 1036   1012   Fred    Nerk       single      150      150  |
| 1037   1013   Adam    McKenzie   double      200      200  |
| 1037   1014   Rose    McKenzie   double      200      100  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
* keep in mind this is only an example - normally there are 24 columns.
```

Although my desired table output is;

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| rID    UID    Name    Surname   Room Type   Total    Paid  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1035   1010   John    Doe        double      200      200  |
|        1011   Jane    Doe        double      200      200  |
| 1036   1012   Fred    Nerk       single      150      150  |
| 1037   1013   Adam    McKenzie   double      200      200  |
|        1014   Rose    McKenzie   double      200      100  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
* keep in mind this is only an example - normally there are 24 columns.
```

---

I have found a few solutions, however the only issue is that in all of the explanations and also in the questions there are only two variables being called for from the database which has left me confused. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30684275/4970703), for example, works when I feed all the variables into arrays and implement them into the code. Although now I have 24 arrays and it really clogs my code. Is there a more efficient solution to this?

Currently, with all the results fed into arrays my code looks as below;

```
$arr = array();

        $a_UID = array(); $a_pdID = array(); $a_name = array(); $a_surname = array(); $a_address = array(); $a_city = array(); $a_ci = array(); $a_co = array();
        $a_transfer = array(); $a_confirm = array(); $a_membership = array(); $a_rtype = array(); $a_notes = array(); $a_entryby = array(); $a_dateentered = array();
        $a_updateby = array(); $a_updatetime = array(); $a_total = array(); $a_paid = array(); $a_pmethod = array(); $a_currency = array(); $a_auth = array(); $a_invoice = array();

        // rID array
        $emp = array();

        while( $guests->fetch() ) {
            array_push($emp, $rID);
            array_push($a_UID, $UID);
            array_push($a_pdID, $pdID);
            array_push($a_name, $name);
            array_push($a_surname, $surname);
            array_push($a_address, $address);
            array_push($a_city, $city);
            array_push($a_ci, $ci);
            array_push($a_co, $co);
            array_push($a_transfer, $transfer);
            array_push($a_confirm, $confirm);
            array_push($a_membership, $membership);
            array_push($a_rtype, $rtype);
            array_push($a_notes, $notes);
            array_push($a_entryby, $entryby);
            array_push($a_dateentered, $dateentered);
            array_push($a_updateby, $updateby);
            array_push($a_updatetime, $updatetime);
            array_push($a_total, $total);
            array_push($a_paid, $paid);
            array_push($a_pmethod, $pmethod);
            array_push($a_currency, $currency);
            array_push($a_auth, $auth);
            array_push($a_invoice, $invoice);

            >which really does not look that good.
```

Comment: Iterate over your result set and for each record only display the `rID` if it _different_ than the one you previously read (and of course always display the `rID` for the first record.  Why is this difficult to implement?

Comment: please provide exact output what your query gives you??

Comment: The implementation isn't the most difficult part, I don't really find having over 25 sets of arrays written over 3 times in a single page much of a eye candy. Thus it disrupts the overflow of the code, I also believe it affects the performance given that I sometimes will call for 1000s of records. Hence why I'm asking whether there is a way to only search through the `rID` and leave the rest
@Priyank57 the exact output is shown in the first example - of course with less variables.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about this is to make a array of keyed off of the grouping field... I'll make the assumption that you are fetching data from a executed statement as an associative array.

```
$res = array();
while ($rec = $dbStmt->fetch()){
    if (!isset($res[ $rec["rID"] ])) $res[ $rec["rID"] ] = array();
    $res[ $rec["rID"] ][] = array_slice($rec, 1);
}
```

Now it's possible to easily get a count of how many records that you have that share a common rID for the rowspan. Then it's just a matter of outputting the table in the format you want.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($res as $rID=>$other){
    $rID = '<td rowspan="', count($other), '">', $rID, '</td>';
    array_shift($other);
    foreach ($order as $otherFields){
        echo "<tr>", $rId, "<td>".implode("</td><td>", $otherFields)."</td></tr>";
        $rId = "";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```